# Convert Twitter4j Status to JSON Object

Tags: android, json, twitter4j

Android 2.3.3

I am integrating Twitter API into my android application. I am using Twitter4j.

I could get the tweets for a particular user, using the below code.

```
Paging paging = new Paging(1, 40);
List<twitter4j.Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("xxx", paging);

Log.d(Const.TAG,"Showing Timeline.");
for (twitter4j.Status status : statuses) {
    String rawJSON = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
}
```

My requirement is that I need to parse the JSON String (rawJSON), to get some other values like, published date and so on.

I am pretty new to JSON parsing esp., with converting things to JSON. All i know in the above code is that, `String rawJSON = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);` converts the `Status Object` to a `String` and I can view it by logging it.

How do I convert this `String` to a `JSONObject` or a `JSONArray`? Can someone provide me with a sample code?

I tried the below code, but it gives an exception

```
try {
    JSONObject tweet = new JSONObject(rawJSON);
    JSONArray textArray = tweet.getJSONArray("text");
    String text = textArray.getString(0);

    Log.d(Const.TAG, "Text = "+text);

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.d(Const.TAG, "Error while converting string to json");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a way to get values from `Status` object without the need to convert it into JSON. Of course this is very basic, by I overlooked it.People who have trouble getting values from Status object, can look at this.

You can get all the values by using the object of `Status`.
For example, if "status" is an object of Status, we can get the text of the tweet, by using, status.getText() and the user value by using status.user() and so on. Just work on the status object a bit and you will find all the values you need.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my code to parse a Twitter4j `Status`. This example get the language of the tweet.

```
//Status To JSON String
String statusJson = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);

//JSON String to JSONObject
JSONObject JSON_complete = new JSONObject(statusJson);

//We get another JSONObject
JSONObject JSON_user = JSON_complete.getJSONObject("user");

//We get a field in the second JSONObject
String languageTweet = JSON_user.getString("lang");
```